# group_by and global mean within a single dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way using `dplyr` to summarise using `group_by()` then take a global mean, then add that to the same data frame without having to create a second dataframe?

Right now I am doing this like this:

```
library(dplyr)

speciesiris <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(mpw=mean(Petal.Width)) 

iris %>%
  summarise(mpw=mean(Petal.Width)) %>%
  mutate(Species="All Species") %>%
  bind_rows(speciesiris)
```

One potential pitfall here is that I want not the mean of means but rather a global mean or at least the option of both. So is there a better way of doing this hopefully all in one pipe?

Comment: Try `iris %>% select(Petal.Width, Species) %>% bind_rows(., data.frame(Petal.Width=mean(.$Petal.Width), Species="All Species")) %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mpw = mean(Petal.Width))`

Comment: You could just expand your speciesiris variable in the second statement: `iris %>% summarise(mpw=mean(Petal.Width)) %>% mutate(Species="All Species") %>% bind_rows(iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mpw=mean(Petal.Width)) )`

Comment: @fishtank Wow a pipe within a pipe. I'd never even considered such a thing. Sort of defeats the purpose of making dplyr pipes more readable code but it certainly works. Did you want to make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @boshek posted into answer.

Comment: At times, I think this type of layout is more beneficial for analysis -- e.g., comparing the by-group means vs. the total: `iris %>%
  mutate(all_species = mean(Petal.Width)) %>%
  group_by(Species, all_species) %>%
  summarise(mpw = mean(Petal.Width)) %>% mutate(delta = mpw - all_species)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line to do everything (but not recommended):

```
iris %>% summarise(mpw=mean(Petal.Width))        # Global mean
     %>% mutate(Species="All Species")
     %>% bind_rows(
            iris %>% group_by(Species)           # Mean by Species
                 %>% summarise(mpw=mean(Petal.Width))
                  )
```